# Sample random row from data frame that isn't subset of previous sample in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, sample

Newbie here. My problem has 2 steps. I would like to sample a number of rows (3) from a data frame and then take a second sample (1 row) which is not in the first sample.

```
#here is my data frame
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))

#here is my first sample with 3 rows
sample_1<- df[sample(nrow(df), 3), ]


#here is my second sample
sample_2 <- df[sample(nrow(df), 1), ]
```

I want the second sample to not be a part of the first sample.

I appreciate your help. Thank you!

Hello! Thanks once again for the response to this. I have a follow up question to this. If I needed to run this on a large dataset, using a FOR loop, so that it ran the code for every iteration but selected a different group each time the loop ran, would that be possible?

Comment: Don't do this in two steps - sample 4 rows from the data frame and then assign the first 3 to the first sample, and the 4th to the second sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GregorThomas' suggestion is likely best, given what we know: sample four rows, and then take one row as your `sample_2` and the rest are in `sample_1`.

```r
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))
( samples <- sample(nrow(df), size = 4) )
# [1] 6 8 4 9
sample_1 <- df[ samples[-1], ]
sample_2 <- df[ samples[1],,drop = FALSE ]
sample_1
#            X1         X2
# 8 -0.09465904 -2.6564554
# 4  0.63286260 -0.2787888
# 9  2.01842371 -2.4404669
sample_2
#           X1        X2
# 6 -0.1061245 0.6359504
```

However, if for some reason your sampling requires something *else*, then you can restrict your second sampling to those not included in the first. A good way is if you have a unique id of some form in each row:

```r
df$id <- seq_len(nrow(df))
df
#             X1         X2 id
# 1   1.37095845  1.3048697  1
# 2  -0.56469817  2.2866454  2
# 3   0.36312841 -1.3888607  3
# 4   0.63286260 -0.2787888  4
# 5   0.40426832 -0.1333213  5
# 6  -0.10612452  0.6359504  6
# 7   1.51152200 -0.2842529  7
# 8  -0.09465904 -2.6564554  8
# 9   2.01842371 -2.4404669  9
# 10 -0.06271410  1.3201133 10

sample_1 <- df[sample(nrow(df), 3), ]
sample_1
#           X1         X2 id
# 6 -0.1061245  0.6359504  6
# 2 -0.5646982  2.2866454  2
# 5  0.4042683 -0.1333213  5
subdf <- df[ !df$id %in% sample_1$id, ]
sample_2 <- subdf[sample(nrow(subdf), 1), ]
sample_2
#         X1         X2 id
# 7 1.511522 -0.2842529  7
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks once again for the response to this. I have a follow up question to this. If I needed to run this on a large dataset, using a FOR loop, so that it ran the code for every iteration but selected a different group each time the loop ran, would that be possible?